# How do I change the business owner of a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to change a business owner of a Facebook application? If yes, how?

Comment: This isn't really related to programming i think

Comment: But I think it's helpful to programmer, that why I ended up here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes. In the apps dashboard there is a section called Role. There you can add a new user as admin and remove the current one. The previous user will no longer be able to make changes in the app.

1. Goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Select you application.
3. Click Edit App
4. Click Roles
5. Add new user as admin
6. Remove the current one.

Comment: Not working in our case « Business Manager » is not present in « Admin »

Comment: @AntoineF. How did you manage to do it with you Business Manager ?

Comment: @dtdino We took over the connected account via a complex administrative process with Facebook and our notary and paper documents we contacted Facebook by chat)

Comment: @AntoineF. I'm in a similar situation and appreciated your response. How did you contact FB to start the process, and can you please elaborate on what was involved? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/business/help > `Get started` > `Chat with a representative`