# How to migrate a facebook app ownership to Business Manager?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

recently I as developer was invited to a Facebook-account which belongs to a company, and it has already one facebook app. Then I have created another app for this company but somehow the company doesn't own this app, you can see it on the image below:[image]

How can I change it to make the company owning this app? It appears I created it on my developer account and see no way to transfer it. The company has a Business Manager account and we want to use advertising for both apps. The app is live and linked with iOS and Android apps to simplify login, so creating another app is not a solution.

There is a Business Manager section in the Settings - Advanced (Associate your app with a business to use the Business Mapping API), but it asks to create a new Business Manager account and not associate it with existing one. Will it work if I create this Business Manager account and then try that solution - [How do I change the business owner of a Facebook application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7774474/194544)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve it by updating my role in BM to Admin, after that I was able to go to Settings - Advanced - Business Manager (in the facebook app) and link our BM account to the app. The issue is solved.